# como puedo llamar a un arreglo de una función a otra en c++

Tags: c++, array

Estoy haciendo un arreglo local en una función llamada verEvento, la cual quiero modificarla pero desde otra funcion distinta, ¿como puedo hacer para mandarla a llamar?

```
void verEvento() {
string infoEventos [5][5]={
        { "Hacketon ", "", "", " ", " "},
        {"Seguridad informatica", "",""," ", " "},
        {"Enero 12", "",""," "," "},
        {"cantidad de alumnos: 123", " ", " ", " "," "},
        {"1B"," ", "  ", " "," "}
};

for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if (infoEventos[i][j] != " "){
            cout << infoEventos[0][j] <<"\n"<<infoEventos[1][j] << "\n". 
 <<infoEventos[2][j]<< "\n"<<infoEventos[3][j]<<"\n"<<infoEventos[4][j]<<"\n"<<"-- 
  -------------"<<endl;
        }
    }
    i=3;
}
}
```

En la funcion anterior es donde creo el arreglo y donde igual la muestro pero quiero modificarla en la funcion siguiente

```
void registroEvento() {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todas las variables tienen su tiempo de vida. En cuanto la función termine sus variables locales dejan de existir.

Una solución es poner las variables en otra parte para que vivan más tiempo y pasarlas como parámetro. Por ejemplo, en la función `main` aseguras que viva durante la mayor parte de la ejecución del programa:

```
void verEvento(string infoEventos[5][5]){
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
            if (infoEventos[i][j].length() > 0)
            cout << infoEventos[i][j] << "\n";
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    string infoEventos[5][5]={
        {"Hacketon ", "", "", " ", " "},
        {"Seguridad informatica", "",""," ", " "},
        {"Enero 12", "",""," "," "},
        {"Cantidad de alumnos: 123", " ", " ", " "," "},
        {"1B"," ", "  ", " "," "}
    };

    verEvento(infoEventos);
    ...
}
```