# porque no me deja llamar a mis arreeglos en c++

Tags: c++, array

Estoy tratando de llamar a mis arreglos que tengo alojadas en una funcion llamada menualumno(), pero al momento de mandarlas a llamar desde la funcion menuprofesor() me marca un error el cual no entiendo porque sale

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void menualumno();
void menuprofesor(string user2,string estadia[2][2],string estancia[2][2] );
void iniciosesion();
int main();
```

arriba es donde estoy declarando las varriables y los arreglos que estoy llamando.
en la funcion de abajo es donde tengo creadas los arreglos

```
void menualumno(){
int matricula;
int opcion;
int estadiaseleccionada;
int estanciaseleccionada;
string estadia[2][2]={
        {"empresa","empresa2"},
        {"proyecto","proyecto2"}
};
string estancia[2][2]={
        {"tienda1","tienda1"},
        {"trabajo","trabajo2"}
};
}
```

en la funcion de abajo es donde estoy mandando a llamar a esas variables de la funcion menualumno

```
void menuprofesor(string user2, string estadia[2][2],string estancia[2][2]){
cout<<"profesora: "<<user2<<endl;
cout<<"buenas tardes estos son las solicitudes de los alumnos pendientes"<<endl;


}

en la siguiente funcion llamada iniciosesion es donde se presenta el problema en el segundo if el cual es menuprofesor(user2, estadia, estancia); porquee me marca error en estadia y estancia, segun yo esta bien declarada

void iniciosesion(){
int pass1 = 123, pass2=1234, pas;
string user1 = "alumno",user2 ="diana", use;

cout << "Ingrese un usuario..."<<endl;
cin >> use;
cout << "Ingrese pass..."<<endl;
cin>> pas;

if(pas == pass1 && use == user1) {
    cout <<"hola alumno "<<user1<<endl;
    menualumno();
} else if(pas == pass2 && use == user2){
    menuprofesor(user2, estadia, estancia);
} else {
    cout <<"Usuario no existe" <<endl;
}
}



int main(){

iniciosesion();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hay 2 cosas a tener en cuenta, lo que ya te respondí en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/569472/169744): Las variables a las que quieres acceder viven en la función `menualumno`. Estas variables se crean cuando llamas a la función `menualumno` y se destruyen cuando la función termina. Y que el ámbito de la variables es esa función. Mueve las variables que quieras tener en común a donde puedas pasarlas como parámetros, por ejemplo la función `iniciosesion` o fuera de las funciones, a un ámbito "global".

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como puedo llamar a un arreglo de una función a otra en c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/569451/como-puedo-llamar-a-un-arreglo-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-a-otra-en-c)